# remove the first major version of a doc powershell

Tags: document-library, powershell, version-history

I am uploading a file into sharepoint and changing the metadata like so

```
            $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
            $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
            $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
            $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
            if(!($file -match $pat)){
                $FileCreationInfo.URL = $newfile
            }else{
                $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
            }
            $Upload = $DestinationFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
            $Context.Load($Upload)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-host "Adding the meta data to the document in O365"
            $ListItem = $Upload.ListItemAllFields;
            $Listitem["Modified"] = $ModDateSP
            $Listitem["Created"] = $DateSP
            $Listitem["Author"] = $author  
            $Listitem["Editor"] = $lastSaved  

            $ListItem.Update()

            $Context.Load($Upload)
            $Context.ExecuteQuery()
                                if($Upload.CheckOutType -ne "none")
            {
                $Upload.CheckIn("Checked in by Administrator", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
            }
```

This successfully uploads the file and adds the metadata, however it uploads 2 major version. Is there anyway to get it so it only uploads the major version when the meta data has been changed? or removing the first major version?